# How do I reset switch case?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public void Console(List<Keys> keys)
        {
            clickNo ++;

            start = DateTime.Now;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 1;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

            switch (clickNo)
            {
                case 1:
                    DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.NormalOperation); break;
                case 2:
                    DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays); break;
                case 3:
                    DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Dontdisplayoverlays); break;
            }

        }
```

clickNo is global int variable.
I make the three cases in this case it's by using the keys 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

But I want that after three times if I make again 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> it will start over again case 1 case 2 case3 ...

Now after the third case it's not doing anything.

Comment: Tip: Hiding `break;` off to the right can be rather confusing. Depending on the width of the editor window and other statement(s) on the line a casual reader may miss a critical change in flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reset the counter after the last case:

```
case 3:
    DoRequest();
    clickNo = 0;
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Console(List<Keys> keys)
        {
            clickNo ++;

            start = DateTime.Now;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 1;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

            switch (clickNo)
            {
                case 1:
                    DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.NormalOperation); 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays); 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    DoRequest(ScreenshotRequest.DannysCommands.Dontdisplayoverlays); 
                    clickNo = 0;
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Just set to 0 in the last case.